# Surface plot for square matrix and labelling data points

Tags: matlab

I want to plot 3D surface plots (which look like mountains). My data are square matrices. I want to be able to label the data where there is kind of a big cliff.

How can I go about it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For a single 2D matrix you can use [SURF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/surf.html) function to plot 3D surface:

```
% generate random square 2D matrix 20x20
x = rand(20);
% make some (10) mountains
x(randi(numel(x),10,1))=rand(10,1)+5;
% plot surface
surf(x)
```

How do you want to plot multiple surfaces? On a single figure?

To label the large points lets threshold the data:

```
cutvalue = 1;
iHigh = find(x(:) > cutvalue);
[irow,icol] = ind2sub(size(x), iHigh);
hold on
plot3(icol, irow, x(iHigh), 'ro')
hold off
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for something like 'meshgrid'. I did not know earlier that there was a function like this. How do I get my sqaure matrix data into it?